# How to verify if pmset works correctly?

Tags: macos, logs, power-management, pmset

Is there any log, where I can see what `pmset` did and when?

I am thinking about scheduling my macbook power on and the power off and scheduling some job in between to see if it worked, but is there any better way (some power management log file etc.)?

Comment: Pmset -g log ; also check the system log as that's where the kernel logs other startup info.

Answer (score 1):

`$ pmset -g schedule` will show you scheduled events.  John Keates' comment shows you how to review the log file as well:

> Pmset -g log ; also check the system log as that's where the kernel
>   logs other startup info. – John Keates Oct 24 at 2:48